# How find K in KNN

Tags: r

I was recreating the example code

```
# k-NN using caret:
library(ISLR)
library(caret)

 # Split the data:


    data(iris)
    indxTrain <- createDataPartition(y = iris$Sepal.Length,p = 0.75,list = FALSE)
    training <- iris[indxTrain,]
    testing <- iris[-indxTrain,]

# Run k-NN:

    set.seed(400)
    ctrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",repeats = 3)
    knnFit <- train(Species ~ ., data = training, method = "knn", trControl = ctrl, preProcess = c("center","scale"),tuneLength = 20)
    knnFit

# Use plots to see optimal number of clusters:
# Plotting yields Number of Neighbours Vs accuracy (based on repeated cross validation)
plot(knnFit)
```

---

With above example , taken and tried on my dataset
but while running i am getting error

```
set.seed(400)
ctrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",repeats = 3)
knnFit <- train(Engine ~ ., data =usedcars2, method = "knn", trControl = ctrl,preProcess = c("center","scale"),tuneLength = 20)
```

Output

```
Error in na.fail.default(list(Engine = c(1582, 1086, 1198, 998, 1197,  : 
  missing values in object
```

can anyone help me out

Comment: The error message indicates you likely have missing values in your data (NA values). Most methods don't tolerate missing data well. You'll need to either drop observations that have missing data or do some type of imputation to fill in missing values.